# Conductor solution to philosophers dinner

Tags: algorithm, concurrency, dining-philosopher

The conductor solution to the philosopher dinner problem as described suggest that a semphore of size four be used and that all philosophers attempt to get left fork before right fork.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem#Conductor_solution

Should the semaphore be used for everybody accessing the left fork and everyone accessing the right fork?

What should a philosopher do if they can get left fork but don't get right fork within specified time? Should they give left fork back?

Does it matter what order philosophers return forks in?

Surely this solution can still result in starvation. For example the wiki says that A and C both have two forks. This means the semaphore will say no more forks to anyone and hang onto the fifth.
The fork between D and E must stay on the table.  Then say A returns his right fork.

Now the semaphore will be back at 3.

D can try again for left fork and then realise he can't get right.
B can only get left. Again no use.

And A could try to pick the right fork again as he already has his left. This means we go around in circle.

I am missing something

help?

Comment: The semaphore should be used before picking up *both* forks, that's the point.

Comment: @Bergi and then increased by two?  so it can never be increased by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe philosophers always return both forks "at the same time". The problem is further simplified by requiring philosophers to acquire the left fork then the right fork. Lock acquisition order really helps to simplify deadlock problems. Following the conductor scheme will guarantee deadlock is not possible.

The extra trick here is that the waiter requires that only 4 of the 5 philosophers may hold forks at one time (so it's more of a counting semaphore, counting philosophers not forks).

Comment: yeah that's it.  Thanks more info here... http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.choi/www/Resource/Semaphore.pdf